# ASP.NET Session Times out more earlier than expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

My current running configuration looks like this

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" protection="All" name="Auth_Cookie" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="30" />
```

so I expect it to at least let the user be logged in for half an hour (if he does not make any requests)

but the session time out is hit like after 3-4 minutes if the user is not active. I mean global.asax's `Session_End` event is hit in this time and then in `Application_PostAcquireRequestState` event I check if any session variables are null and if they are then I sign the user out and redirect him to the log in page. I cant see what is the problem. Am I misunderstanding how this whole works ? what should I do in order to achieve what I want. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the application pool recycled, i.e. is `Application_Start` being hit?

Comment: Application_Start is never hit. I think because when I star the application debugger is not quick enough to attach to the process

Comment: I am constantly rebuilding the solution. is that be it ? can it be clearing session variables ?

Comment: Are you running locally when you see this behaviour?

Comment: yes. it is running on IIS Local configuration my my local machine.

Comment: @Dima the issue you are seeing is most likely to do with using `InProc`, you should [read up](http://forums.asp.net/t/7504.aspx?Understanding+session+state+modes+FAQ) on the differences between session state modes and decide on which one will work best for your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment:

> I am constantly rebuilding the solution. is that be it ? can it be
>   clearing session variables ?

So basically you are recycling the application pool killing everything stored in the session. The biggest problem with ASP.NET Session is that by default it is stored in-memory:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc"
```

This has the drawback that if the application pool is restarted you will lose everything you stored in it. And don't forget that the application pool could be restarted by IIS at any time. For example after some period of inactivity or if some CPU/memory thresholds are reached. Also if you deploy your application in a web farm, InProc session simply won't work because the nodes of your farm cannot share session information.

All those drawbacks are the reasons why I never use ASP.NET Session in my web applications and simply put this in my web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="Off"
```